# There are 3 sections in a question paper with 5 questions each.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are 3 sections in a question paper each containing 5 questions. A candidate has to solve only 5 questions, choosing at least one question from each section. In how many ways can he make his choice?

I have thought of a solution but I am over counting the number of ways.

No. of ways to choose one question from each section = (5C1)^3
No. of questions remaining = 12
No. of ways to pick 2 questions from remaining 12 questions = 12 * 11
Total number of ways = (5C1)^3 * 12 * 11

Can somebody tell me where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He can choose the following combinations of questions from each section:

$(2,2,1);(2,1,2);(1,2,2);(3,1,1);(1,3,1);(1,1,3)$

Each of the first three combinations has $\binom{5}{2}\cdot \binom{5}{2}\cdot \binom{5}{1}$ ways. And each of the next three combinations has $\binom{5}{3}\cdot \binom{5}{1}\cdot \binom{5}{1}$ ways.

In total he can make $3\cdot \left(\binom{5}{2}\cdot \binom{5}{2}\cdot \binom{5}{1}+ \binom{5}{3}\cdot \binom{5}{1}\cdot \binom{5}{1}\right)=2250$ choices.

---

For every section we have one path. We choose 3 question from each section. For every path we have to add ($\text{not multiply}$) the ways

$\left( \binom{5}{1}+\binom{5}{1}+\binom{5}{1}\right)$

Now we make a case decision.

**a)** We choose 2 questions from one (other) section and 2 questions from the remaining section.

$ \binom{5}{2}\cdot \binom{5}{2}$

**b)** We choose 1 questions from one (other) section and 3 questions from the remaining section.

$ \binom{5}{1}\cdot \binom{5}{3}$

Therefore in total we have

$\left( \binom{5}{1}+\binom{5}{1}+\binom{5}{1}\right)\cdot \left(\binom{5}{2}\cdot \binom{5}{2}+ \binom{5}{1}\cdot \binom{5}{3}\right)=2250$

Comment: can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: One problem is $ \binom{5}{1}^3$. It must be  $ \binom{5}{1}^1+\binom{5}{1}^1+ \binom{5}{1}^1$

Comment: Still answer won't match

Comment: What is the answer?

Comment: 2250 is the correct answer

Comment: What is your problem then? Sure from what I´ve written in the comment you have to make some further calculations. You can factor out $\binom51$ from the term of my answer.

Comment: I want to know what's wrong with my solution

Comment: I try my best to match my answer with yours. See my edit. Give a reply if it is clear now.

Comment: @callculus, though I cannot find any fallacy either in your approach or mine (i.e (5C1)^3 * (12C2)), I don't understand why they don't match. My answer is 4 times yours -> where am I going wrong?

Comment: @mettleap Haven´t you understood why you have to add the three $\binom51$ instead of multiplying them? This is the key point where you went wrong. Please think about that. A decision tree might help.

Answer (score -1):

Alternate way to solve:

Total ways to select 5 questions without restrictions: 15C5 = 3003

Case 1: We select all the 5 questions from only one section.

- From Section A only: 5C5 = 1
- From Section C only: 5C5 = 1
- From Section B only: 5C5 = 1

Sub Total = 3

Case 2:

We select 4 questions from only one section.

- 4 from Section A and 1 from Section B: (5C4)(5C1)
- And Vice-versa: 1 from Section A and 4 from Section B: (5C1)(5C4)
- 4 from Section B and 1 from Section C: (5C4)(5C1)
- And Vice-versa: 1 from Section B and 4 from Section C: (5C1)(5C4)
- 4 from Section C and 1 from Section A: (5C4)(5C1)
- And Vice-versa: 1 from Section C and 4 from Section A: (5C1)(5C4)

Adding Everything together: 6 * (5C4)(5C1) = 150

Case 3:

We select 3 questions from one section and 2 questions from another and not selecting anything form the third section.

- 3 from Section A and 2 from Section B: (5C3)(5C2)
- And Vice-versa: 2 from Section A and 3 from Section B: (5C2)(5C3)
- 3 from Section B and 2 from Section C: (5C3)(5C2)
- And Vice-versa: 2 from Section B and 3 from Section C: (5C2)(5C3)
- 3 from Section C and 2 from Section A: (5C3)(5C2)
- And Vice-versa: 2 from Section C and 3 from Section A: (5C2)(5C3)

Adding Everything together: 6 * (5C3)(5C2) = 600

**Finally, Case 1, Case 2 and Case 3 are to be rejected as they are not complying the conditions.**

Required no of ways = Total - (Case 1 ways) - (Case 2 ways) - (Case 3 ways) = 3003 - 3 - 150 - 600 = **2250**